# What are your thoughts on the brave browser?

Tags: privacy, blockchain

I have been playing around with it a little bit and going through the specs. What are your thoughts on it?

brave.com/

Full disclosure: I am not associated with the project at all. Just a curious user.

Comment: Brave is a crappy browser. It is designed to inject ads to users while blocking competitor's ads. The business model is creepy. See [this](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/01/mozilla-co-founder-unveils-brave-a-web-browser-that-blocks-ads-by-default/) for example: `In practice, Brave just sounds like a cash-grab. Brave isn't just a glorified adblocker: after removing ads from a webpage, Brave then inserts its own programmatic ads.`

Comment: Wrong place for this question. See the help section for more information. Not sure where to recommend you ask it. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a browser is based upon another, there is the potential for 1-day exploits (attacker reverse-engineers chromium patch and targets the still vulnerable brave browser, where that patch is still being integrated into their codebase). This is especially likely if the copycat browser has the smaller team.

Comment: This. I often see people believe that forks are more secure, but unless they have access to the private security bug trackers of those browsers, they will be significantly less secure.